# Xamarin iOS: MvvMCross Binding back button of navigationItem

Tags: data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, uinavigationitem

I want to bind the back button of the navigation item and whenever user clicks the back button I want to execute some code binded to it in view model.

My current code:

View:

```
var bSet = this.CreateBindingSet<xView, xViewModel>();
            bSet.Bind(NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem).To(vm => vm.CheckIfLoading);
            //bSet.Bind(NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem).To(vm => vm.CheckIfLoading);
```

ViewModel:

```
private ICommand checkIfLoading;
public xViewModel()
            : base() 
        {
            this.messenger = mvxMessenger;
            checkIfLoading = new MvxCommand(DoRefresh);
        }
public  ICommand CheckIfLoading { get { return checkIfLoading; } }
private async void DoRefresh()
{
  await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

When ever I hit the back button, I want it to hit DoRefresh(), but its not. Can anyone point out the error or help me resolve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to bind `Clicked` to your `ICommand`:

```
this.AddBindings(new Dictionary<object, string>()
{
    { NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem, "Clicked CheckIfLoading" }
});
```

---

**Side note**

The following line might not work if `Clicked` isn't the default binding:
`bSet.Bind(NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem).To(vm => vm.CheckIfLoading);`

Other ways to bind to a specific property can be achieved by using the `.For(labda)` method as following:

`bSet.Bind(NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem).For(lb => lb.Clicked).To(vm => vm.CheckIfLoading);`

But in this case that won't work since `lb.Clicked` expects a left hand sided action ( `+=` or `-=` )

For more information about binding take a look at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/databinding